# React Native, jest test failing, Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, jestjs

I get the this error with my test can anyone help?

```
  Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      32 | export default ThemeContext;
      33 |
    > 34 | export const useThemeContext = () => useContext(ThemeContext);
```

Component:

```
const SearchLocationInput = ({
  onBackPress,
  onChangeText,
  value,
  placeholder,
}) => {
  const theme = useThemeContext();

  const formStyles = getFormsStyleObj({ theme: theme.theme });
  const styles = getSearchLocationStyle({ theme: theme.theme });
  const ContainerStyles = {
    ...styles.container,
  };

  const inputContainerStyle = {
    ...formStyles.input,
    ...styles.inputContainerStyle,
  };

  const InputProps = {
    value,
    inputContainerStyle,
    disabledInputStyle: styles.disabledInputStyle,
    rightIcon: SearchIcon,
    placeholder,
    placeholderTextColor: theme.colors.TEXTGREY,
    onChangeText,
    leftIcon: <BackButton onPress={onBackPress} />,
    leftIconContainerStyle: styles.leftIconContainerStyle,
  };
  return (
    <View style={ContainerStyles}>
      <Input {...InputProps} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@/utils/testUtils';

import SearchLocationInput from '@/modules/maps/SearchLocationInput/SearchLocationInput';

jest.mock('@/services/AsyncStorageService')

const defaultProps = {
    onPress: jest.fn(),
}

const setup = (props) => {
    const newProps = {
        ...defaultProps,
        ...props
    };
    return render(<SearchLocationInput {...newProps} />)
}

const inputText = /Search for a location/i;

test('it renders', () => {
    const { findByPlaceholder } = setup();
    const input = findByPlaceholder(inputText);
    expect(input).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `<SearchLocationInput {...newProps} />` component with its own Provider in the test file (different with real Provider when App is run through Simulator), because `theme` variable is hooked to ThemeContext.

```
const themeContextMock: ThemeContextProps = {
  // Your theme object props
}

const setup = (props) => {
  const newProps = {
    ...defaultProps,
    ...props
  };
  return render( 
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeContextMock}>
      <SearchLocationInput {...newProps} />
    </ThemeContext>
  )
}
```